# Multiprocessing with two functions while sharing data

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, synchronization

I'm new with multiprocessing in Python. I need three functions to run simultaneously while also doing stuff to the same "multiprocessing queues" and exchanging information. My main problem is that when I make any changes to the contents of this queues in any of these functions, the other functions doesn't realize them in real time.

```
def func1(queueFrames):
    a = 0
    while 1 :
        queueFrames.put(a)
        a =+1



def func2(queueFrames):
    while 1:
        print(queueFrames.get())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    queueFrames = mp.Queue()
    queueAirgun = mp.Queue()
    p1 = mp.Process(target=func1,args=(queueFrames,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = mp.Process(target=func2, args=(queueFrames,))
    p2.start()
```

I'm getting this output.

[image]

But I want output to be 1 2 3 4 5 6.... I don't know if it is a synchronization issue.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you realized that you used `a =+ 1` instead of `a += 1`?

Comment: Omg!! Silly me!! I've been trying to solve this issue for days now. Thank u!

Comment: Np, if you could just my answer as solution.
I first commented because I wanted to make sure that it is not a typo in example over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `a =+ 1` is incorrect.
Python only recognizes `+=`.